# Is Node.js only for websites?

Tags: node.js

Is Node.js only for websites? I've read a full sophisticated web server can be done in Node.js, and then many good web apps. But I've also seen someone make a UDP bot for a game. Which got me to ask, can Node.js be used for more than just websites?

Comment: From the node.js website: *"Node's goal is to provide an easy way to build scalable network programs"*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Node.js can be used for many general purpose projects, including command line utilities, bots like the one you mentioned, and more. Node is particularly good at handling a large amount of I/O, since it uses non-blocking I/O mechanisms. While this includes many web applications, it can include anything that spends a lot of time waiting on disk or network access. For example, a UDP bot for a game probably spends most of its time receiving network data about e.g. players' positions.

It's worth noting that, although I/O itself is non-blocking, the JavaScript code that you actually write and execute with Node only happens in a single thread, making Node.js not-so-suitable for some types of applications (lots of data crunching, simulations, etc). There are ways to handle these limitations, such as spawning sub-processes, but it's good to be aware of the limitation.

Comment: I was writing an answer, but yours is very better. You have said it all.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a server-side engine that happens to use JavaScript as its language. It has normal standard libraries and can do pretty much anything that any other stand along programming language with an event loop and standard libraries for i/o, net access, etc. can do.

So no, it's not, but that's certainly the thing it's use for most (just like how Perl or PHP don't need to be used to generate web content)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has an active community making a wide variety of modules for a lot of use cases. Looking at the [core API](http://nodejs.org/api/) will give a good sense of what lower-level building blocks are there, and searching around [NPM](http://npmjs.org/) will provide insight into how the community is leveraging them.

Given that Node.js has a focus on event-based I/O, I would say it performs best when (surprise) there are events to handle -- web apps are a very good example of this. There has also been [a lot of conversation](http://voodootikigod.com/nodebots-the-rise-of-js-robotics/) lately about Node.js in tandem with hardware, which often can follow similar patterns of asynchronous events. The [Johnny-Five library](https://github.com/rwldrn/johnny-five) is worth taking a look at if you're interested in "Nodebots".

There's lots of stuff, though! [voxel.js](http://voxeljs.com/) is one of my favorite projects right now, and relies on Node.js code being packaged for the browser and run client-side.

Node.js can absolutely be used for much more than just websites, but certainly some projects are more co-aligned with its affordances.